Using a UserControl to bind different DataGrids to DataRowDetails of an outer DataGrid
I have an OuterDataGrid. For every row, the RowDetails show an InnerDataGrid.
Example: this is the OuterDataGrid:



Kid
Age
Status




John
22
online


Kevin
23
offline



After clicking onto the first row, then the RowDetails shows the InnerDataGrid:



School
City




AA
London


BB
Miami


CC
Paris



But when clicking onto the second row, then the RowDetails shows another InnerDataGrid:



University
Alcohol
Volume




DDD
Beer
5,6%


CCC
Vodka
37,5%



This is cool and works, if I allow only one RowDetails at one time to be displayed. But that is not what I want.
So, after opening two RowDetails, I want to display two different InnerDataTables. I think working with UserControls could work. I hope this is understandable, with my little "Drawing". I cannot draw a table inside a table with just text... :D
Currently I display the same InnerDataGrid for both RowDetails. It is clear to me, why this happens: Opening the first RowDetails, the correct InnerDataGrid is displayed. But when opening the second RowDetails, this overrides the first RowDetails DataGrid and my GUI displays wrong data. See my code below.
I implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Every DataGrid in my GUI will be generated by code. Before running the code, I never know how many rows or columns a DataTable has. I neither know how many InnerDataGrids I need to display.
Can I have like a list of UserControls that is built while the code is running and depending on the SelectedItem of the OuterDataGrid I load the InnerDataGrid? How can I achieve that the already opened RowDetail will not change after displaying another RowDetail?
This is my Main.xaml:
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
      <ItemsControl>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentSpecialTable.CurrentTable.DefaultView}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="False" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="2000" RowHeight="20" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">

          <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <myControl:InnerDgUserControl>
                    
              </myControl:InnerDgUserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

        </DataGrid>
      </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

This is my UserControl for the InnerDataGrid:
<Grid>
  <DataGrid x:Name="innerDg" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DetailsTable.DefaultView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            MaxWidth="2560" MaxHeight="2000" RowHeight="20" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">

  </DataGrid>
</Grid>

I search for an idea to solve my problem. Is my problem solveable? I think it is, why should it not work to display different DataTables in different RowDetails. I think the big problem is: what do I write in my .xaml to get the job done? This cracks my head.

I'd suggest that you take a step back and initially focus on the data rather than the UI. Create a class structure and logic to hold the required items - clarify what is a child of what, and what determines which child items are added for each main item. Once you have that sorted then you can start work on the UI. Give the hierarchical nature of your data, I'd suggest using a TreeView control, with data templates for each class type, rather than DataGrids

All instances of InnerDgUserControl bind to the same property DetailsTable. Hence, they all show the same data.  You have to provide a different data source for each row.

Binding the internals of a UserControl or custom control to any DataContext is an anti-pattern. If your control needs external data you must implement a dependency property. Bind the internal element to this dependency property and then set this property externally from the (data) context where it is used. You should design a control as if there is nothing like a DataContext. And you should not add elements directly to an ItemsControl as well. Use DataTemplates.

"Every DataGrid in my GUI will be generated by code. Before running the code, I never know how many rows or columns a DataTable has." - Sounds suspicious to me. Your OuterDataGrid looks to have a fix column count. You should create a simple data class for this specific table instead of using a DataTable. Then let this class expose a DataTable via an e.g. Details property and bind the row detail's InnerDataGrid to it. This way each row has its individual DataTable.

i think exactly this is the solution to my problem: Then let this class expose a DataTable via an e.g. Details property and bind the row detail's InnerDataGrid to it. This way each row has its individual DataTable. how would i implement this in my xaml?
